# Count registered users by date

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help  with this MySQL query. I have the following fields in the DB

```
id     created_on            
1      2016-02-15 12:47:09     
2      2016-02-24 12:47:09    
3      2016-02-29 12:47:09    
4      2016-03-11 12:47:09    
5      2016-03-15 12:47:09    
6      2016-03-22 12:47:09    
7      2016-04-10 12:47:09    
8      2016-04-11 12:47:09
```

I need to count the total records for the past 4 months. i did this so far,

```
SELECT YEAR(created_on) as year_val, MONTH(created_on) as month_val ,COUNT(*) as total
FROM `user`
GROUP BY YEAR(created_on), MONTH(created_on)
```

thanks

Comment: Does it not return what you expect? If not, what does it return instead? Is there an error or some other problem?

Comment: @Don'tPanic it returns everything (year and month) not the past 4 months

Comment: In your WHERE you'll have to add a test - like month_val between the current date and an INTERVAL of 4 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

WHERE created_on >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 4 MONTH)

it will return

```
"year_val"   "month_val"   "total"
"2016"       "3"           "1"
"2016"       "4"           "2"
"2016"       "5"           "1"
```

Answer (score -4):

SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE created_on >= '2016-02-15 12:47:09' AND created_on <= '2016-06-15 12:47:09';

should work for your counter